# How to create a batch file to reboot into Android installed on a second SSD?

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, android

I have Android installed on a second SSD on an Windows 8.1 machine. At present I can boot to Android via f12 after reboot to boot options etc. or by going to settings, power and holding down shift while clicking restart and following the additonal steps at the next menu. I would like a simple shortcut to perform the action instead of these multiple steps. I understand the script to restart as a starting point (Shutdown /r /t 0) How do I point it to my secondary SSD which is ATA HDD2 as identified in the boot menu?

Comment: There may be a solution I'm not aware of, but the issue is that batch only works to send commands in Windows. Changing your boot device is a choice not made by Windows but by the BIOS, the hardware of your computer. Batch can only act upon BIOS and hardware IF the BIOS and hardware have been programmed to allow this. Considering the security implications of this sort of thing, I'd guess that this is not possible.

Comment: @music2myear is correct. For better control, I would recommend installing "android" to a virtual machine inside of windows instead of having it be a standalone OS.

Answer (score 0):

Batch only works on Windows commands.

Changing/selecting in the Boot Order is a BIOS-level (that is, hardware-level) event.

Generally speaking, Windows only has very limited access to generate BIOS-level commands, and only IF and HOW the BIOS may be configured to allow such control.

So no, it is very unlikely you'll be able to create a command in any common Windows scripting language that will trigger a reboot with selection of a different boot device.